# Auto enabling and disabling chrome extension at particular time?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How can I enable/disable any chrome extension at particular time automatically even during my sleep.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by creating another extension with [chrome.alarms.create](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/alarms/#method-create) to define the times and [chrome.management.setEnabled](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/management/#method-setEnabled) to toggle the extensions.

Comment: My idea is looking new because no such extension exists in chrome store. Such extension can save energy and consumption of ram, processor and systems resources extra.